# Undo an autocorrected word on the iPhone keyboard

Tags: keyboard, autocorrect

The iPhone's keyboard seems extremely diligent with its autocorrection.

Problem is, I very frequently type words that aren't in the dictionary (proper names, foreign words, etc...).

In some Android keyboards, there is a function to undo a word that was autocorrected to the original spelling—is such a functionality available in iPhone's default keyboard?

Comment: I saw a couple of related questions on the site but they all seemed to be about non-IPhone keyboard

Comment: answered both of your questions, let me know if you have any questions and whether they help you or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a pretty simple way to undo any auto-correct on the iPhone's keyboard: if you type a word that autocorrects, just hit the delete key, and a popup of suggestions for that word will pop up. The first suggestion is the word you had before it was autocorrected.

So say you type `thid`, which autocorrects to `this`, but you really meant to type `thid`. 
**Just type `thid`, then hit space, then backspace, then a popup with the word `thid` will appear. Tap it to undo the autocorrection.**

[Here's a video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4fjCCVHGK_lZ3FMN1J5VHBjck0/view?usp=sharing).

[image: Image of undoing autocorrect in Notes]